# How do I get the API specification or schema for a custom REST endpoint?

Tags: rest-api, api, json, rest, schema

#### How do I get the API specification or schema for a custom REST endpoint?

I'm looking for something basic, similar to the examples provided within this documentation for [OpenAPI Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/). The end goal is for easier integrations with vendors and Postman. I'm hoping this is something available in Salesforce or if someone has an external tool instead of building one from scratch.

**UPDATE:** As of this update, there is a pilot for OpenAPI 3.0 Specification in Spring '21 but looks to only cover 4 of the most commonly used sObjects.

[Trailblazer Idea - Ability to generate OpenAPI docs for REST-ful integration](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cQsxQAE)
[SALESFORCE SPRING ’21 RELEASE NOTES - OpenAPI 3.0 Specification (Pilot)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_openapi_spec_pilot.htm&type=5&release=230)

Comment: Not available out of the box, you have to build it by hand. Salesforce is [working on](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cQsxQAE) doing this out of the box for a few _standard_ APIs. Custom APIs you have to handle yourself.

Comment: @identigral Thanks! That's kinda what I had figured. Glad to see there is some progress toward OpenAPI specifications.

Comment: Since custom APIs have entirely free reign with rsqusst bodies and responses, including whether to use JSON, to return multi-part or even binary inputs or results I don't see that Salesforce could really ever generate the spec for these. In some limited cases they could generate boilerplate that you could update to cover required parameter combos, but really this would be a small subset of possible cases.